# Having my web application send update command to my wpf application

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf

Im starting a new project for a client. The client want to build an application with a asp.net mvc web site (for use on iphone and android). And a WPF application tp present data. The general idea is that the user configure several resources (images, video etc.). And then these are associated with this user account. The customer - now in a presentation scenario (with a cusomer, conference, or the like) starts the wpf client on a labtop and connects it to a projector. With his iPad or smart phone he browses to the web page and now has the thumbnails of the images he uploade. When he preses a thumbnail the command will be sent through a webservice to the WPF client and this client will be able to display the image.

Given the images and all this is properly downloade etc. how would one go about sending (pushing) from the website (through iPad/smart device) to the WPF Client? Im thinking on using the IIS and hosting a WCF service through that. How would that scale, how would i manage the connection of e.g. 100 WPF clients on different accounts? - how well does it scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved/Workaround: Implemented a WCF duplex http channel, that allows me to do just that.